# Conditional column header in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I am in a situation which is easy to see but I can't solve it anyway. The problem is I want a column name `header` (not the value) different based on a condition. I want like the following thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CASE bool_var WHEN 1 
                               THEN SUM(r.amount_dbl) AS RECEIVED 
                               ELSE  "0" AS Issued END) 
FROM table
```

Is it possible? Please help in this regard.

Comment: Does your `bool_var` vary with reach row?

Comment: why are you trying to aggregate on row? your query seems weird even without column name issue.

Comment: what is the problem to have both columns?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: yes, bool_var vary with each row.

Comment: @frail: I need aggregate here what can I do in any other way?

Comment: @newtover: actually, I will show both column, here i show only one as an example. In fact, the output will be "when there is received item, there is no issued and vice versa". I hope, i can make it clear.

Comment: @sarwar026 CASE is a "per row operation" so aggregating doesn't really works as you intend.

Comment: @frail: Then it's really a problem for me. But it seems to work in my case, I don't know whether I am missing anything!!

Comment: @sarwar026 if you can put some example data and your requested result people can help you more.

Comment: @frail: Actually, i just understand that it is not needed since i need both column and hence i just ignore it. I also want to close the question as i thought it is closed instantly but it didn't. sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to have diffirent column names inside "case" statement. But as I commented about your query seems a bit off as well. Just a wild guess but are you trying to achieve this? :

```
SELECT
   (CASE bool_var WHEN 1 THEN "RECEIVED"
    ELSE "ISSUED" END) as condition,
   SUM(r.amount_db1) as condition_sum
FROM table r
GROUP BY bool_var
```

Edit:
This one is ugly, slow and wrong in sense of sql query but here it goes:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount_db1) AS RECEIVED,
    (SELECT SUM(amount_db1) FROM table WHERE bool_var != 1) AS ISSUED
FROM table
WHERE bool_var = 1
```

Comment: Your solution seems to return two row, one as "RECEIVED" and another row as "ISSUED". But my purpose is to show it in same row. thats the problem. Thanks for your time, but i am in trouble till now.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am really a stupid. There is no need to dynamic header name, I just found. Since I need to show two column, so it can have static name also. Really sorry to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

A column cannot have a different name for each row.

Comment: No, it's actually a column value.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not set conditional column titles. The case-function is working row per row. What sould be the column title if rows 1, 3 and 5 produce the header "odd" while rows 2,4, and 6 produce the header "even"?